# Discord.js Ignoring Other Emojis

Tags: discord.js, emoji

i'm working on a function reaction role bot. I'm trying to find out how I would add a filter that would ignore other emojis outside the ones I have assigned. The bot works fine except when I or others try to react with the bot with emojis outside of the ones I have assigned.

```
client.on('message', message => {

    if(message.author.bot || message.embeds)

    embedMsg = message.embeds.find(msg => msg.title === 'Server Roles') ? message : undefined
      if(embedMsg) 
      {

      embedMsg.react('755602275963109536')
            .then
(reaction => reaction.message.react('755604749814071366'))
            .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('755605241067601960'))
            .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('755604978571280466'))
            .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('755604795292909589'))
            .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('755605048666620075'))
            .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('755604953229164594'))
            .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('755604994656436346'))
            .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('755605995195072603'))
            .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('755605032124022814'))
            .then(reaction => reaction.message.delete(20000))
            .then(msg => console.log("Deleted message"))
            .catch(() => console.error('One of the emojis failed to react.'));
            return;
      }

client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if (user.bot) return;
   
    var roleName = reaction.emoji.name;
    console.log(roleName);
    var role = reaction.message.guild.roles.find(
     role => role.name.toLowerCase() === roleName.toLowerCase()
    );
    var member = reaction.message.guild.members.find(
     (member) => member.id === user.id
    );
   //remove role
    if (member.roles.has(role.id)) {
     member
      .removeRole(role.id)
      .then((member) => {
       console.log(
        'Removed' + member.user.username + ' from the ' + role.name + ' role.'
       );
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error);
    //add role  
    } else {
     member
      .addRole(role.id)
      .then((member) => {
       console.log(
        'Added ' + member.user.username + ' to the ' + role.name + ' role.'
       );
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error);
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an array of accepted emoji IDs, and test each one against the reaction given.

```js
const array = ['ID #1, 'ID #2', 'ID #3', 'etc.'];
if (!array.includes(reaction.emoji.id)) return;
```